# How to generate spool file in my local folder

Tags: plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper, plsqldeveloper

I want to generate a spool file with a file name and store it into my local folder whose path I can provide in the code itself. How to do that? Suppose below is the code where I want script to be generated in the separate SQL file

```
declare
 lv_str varchar2(1000);
begin
for c in(select distinct a.table_name as table_name, 
                b.table_name as parent_table_name ,
                a.owner
           from all_constraints a, 
                all_constraints b 
          where a.r_constraint_name = b.constraint_name 
            and a.constraint_type   = 'R'
            and b.constraint_type   = 'P'
            and a.owner             = b.owner   -- if parent and child belongs to the same schema
            and a.owner             = 'SCOTT'
       ) loop
 lv_str :='DROP TABLE ' || c.owner || '.' || c.table_name || '; -- ' || c.parent_table_name;
 dbms_output.put_Line (lv_str );
 end loop;
end;
```

/

Also, one small help If I want to drop the table names would it require deleting the parent table as well. If yes, how to delete table_name and parent_table_name?(as per the code) at once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the 'cd' command, avail in SQL Developer and it's CLI counterpart, SQLcl. SQLcl is like SQLPlus, but better.

This will also work in SQL Developer, just execute via F5.

```
SQL> cd c:\users\jdsmith\desktop
SQL> set serveroutput on
SQL> spool so4.txt
SQL> declare
  2   lv_str varchar2(1000);
  3  begin
  4  for c in(select distinct a.table_name as table_name,
  5                  b.table_name as parent_table_name ,
  6                  a.owner
  7             from all_constraints a,
  8                  all_constraints b
  9            where a.r_constraint_name = b.constraint_name
 10              and a.constraint_type   = 'R'
 11              and b.constraint_type   = 'P'
 12              and a.owner             = b.owner   -- if parent and child belongs to the same schema
 13              and a.owner             = 'HR'
 14         ) loop
 15   lv_str :='DROP TABLE ' || c.owner || '.' || c.table_name || '; -- ' || c.parent_table_name;
 16   dbms_output.put_Line (lv_str );
 17   end loop;
 18  end;
 19* /
DROP TABLE HR.EMPLOYEES; -- EMPLOYEES
DROP TABLE HR.DBMSHP_FUNCTION_INFO; -- DBMSHP_RUNS
DROP TABLE HR.JOB_HISTORY; -- EMPLOYEES
DROP TABLE HR.DBMSHP_PARENT_CHILD_INFO; -- DBMSHP_FUNCTION_INFO
DROP TABLE HR.EMPLOYEES; -- JOBS
DROP TABLE HR.JOB_HISTORY; -- JOBS
DROP TABLE HR.JOB_HISTORY; -- DEPARTMENTS
DROP TABLE HR.DEPARTMENTS; -- LOCATIONS
DROP TABLE HR.LOCATIONS; -- COUNTRIES
DROP TABLE HR.WINE_REVIEWS; -- WINE_VARIETIES
DROP TABLE HR.DEPARTMENTS; -- EMPLOYEES
DROP TABLE HR.COUNTRIES; -- REGIONS
DROP TABLE HR.EMPLOYEES; -- DEPARTMENTS


PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> spool off;
SQL>
```

Then if I go look at the so4.txt file on my desktop --
[image]

Comment: You don't even have to use "cd".  You can just put the full path to the spool file in the "spool" command line": spool c:\users\jdsmith\desktop\so4.txt.

Comment: Yes, but cd is easier when writing multiple files.

Answer (score 1):

If you're doing it from PL/SQL, then you could `set serveroutput on` and `spool` into a local file (but also get some *garbage*, i.e. code itself):

```
SQL> spool a.sql
SQL>
SQL> begin
  2    for cur_r in (select tname from tab) loop
  3      dbms_output.put_line('desc ' || cur_r.tname);
  4    end loop;
  5  end;
  6  /
desc DEPT
desc EMP
desc EMPLOYEES

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> spool off
```

Result:

```
SQL> $type a.sql
SQL>
SQL> begin
  2    for cur_r in (select tname from tab) loop
  3      dbms_output.put_line('desc ' || cur_r.tname);
  4    end loop;
  5  end;
  6  /
desc DEPT
desc EMP
desc EMPLOYEES

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> spool off

SQL>
```

---

Alternatively, use `UTL_FILE` package, but it creates a file in a directory on a database server (as you have to use Oracle directory object which *usually* points there). But then you'd get a nice file.